# Placing custom control inside InfoWindow using Google Maps API

Tags: api, google-maps, controls, infowindow

Is it possible to place an array of Custom Controls inside an InfoWindow using Google Maps API? If so, how can it be done? I tried it but couldn't find a way to write the API code inside the 'content' field of InfoWindow.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom control"?

Comment: it could be an option list, buttons with an images...could be anything really. By custom controls, I mean those controls apart from the one that are directly provided by the API (like zoom control, scale, etc.)

Comment: you can add any HTML to the `InfoWindow`, and beyond that, you can work with Javascript and event listeners in the usual way.  So I think the answer is "yes" ... if you need more detailed info, I would suggest please asking a more specific question.